# How to create IPA in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ipa

I'm new in Xcode, I have Apple Developer account, but I don't know how to make IPA file.
Can anybody explain, step by step, how to make IPA file in Xcode 7, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Connect iOS Device and then Archive menu active after clicking Xcode product menu and go further.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to have an iOS device connected to your computer. Next, go to the Product menu at the top and select Archive. This will archive the current build and show you all of your Archives in the Organizer. In the Organize, press Export, and select the appropriate option (My guess is you want for Apple Store Deployment). This will place the ipa file onto your desktop.